# C Array being overwritten?

Tags: c, pointers, linear-programming, segmentation-fault, glpk

When I run this program : http://hastebin.com/asorawoluw.m

I get this error in GDB :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401f91 in resoudre (baie=...) at lineaire.c:291
291         printf("type[%d] : %d\n", i, helper_glpk.col_bounds[i]->type);
```

When i ask gdb to `print i`I get :

```
$1 = 1
```

So the first iteration is failing, but I'm sure I did write into the first case of `helper_glpk.col_bounds` at the line 200-204 and I did malloc so there's no way (I think ?) that my data is being overwritten or deleted.. so I don't understand why I get this error.

Edit : here's the minimal code :
My structs :

```
typedef struct Bounds Bounds;
struct Bounds
{
    int type;
    double lb;
    double ub;
};

typedef struct HelperGlpk HelperGlpk;
struct HelperGlpk
{
    double *matrix_coefs;
    double *obj_coefs;
    Bounds **row_bounds;
    Bounds **col_bounds;
    int *column_of_coef;
    int *row_of_coef;
    int cpt_coef;
    int cpt_contrainte;
};
```

My functions to generates constraint :

```
void genere_contrainte_1(int i, int j, HelperGlpk *helper_glpk, Baie baie){         
    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_ouverture_serveur(i)]->type = GLP_DB;
    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_ouverture_serveur(i)]->lb = 0;
    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_ouverture_serveur(i)]->ub = 1;

    helper_glpk->cpt_coef++;

    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_connexion(i, j, baie.nbr_serveur)]->type = GLP_LO;
    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_connexion(i, j, baie.nbr_serveur)]->lb = 0;
    helper_glpk->col_bounds[index_connexion(i, j, baie.nbr_serveur)]->ub = 0;

    helper_glpk->cpt_coef++;
}
```

and the main program is :

```
void resoudre(Baie baie){

    glp_prob *lp;

    const int nbr_rows = baie.nbr_client + baie.nbr_serveur * baie.nbr_client; // nombre de contrainte
    const int nbr_colums = baie.nbr_serveur + baie.nbr_serveur * baie.nbr_client; // nombre de variable
    const int nbr_coefs = 3 * baie.nbr_serveur * baie.nbr_client;

    int i, j;

    HelperGlpk helper_glpk;

    helper_glpk.matrix_coefs = malloc((nbr_coefs + 1) * sizeof(double));
    helper_glpk.matrix_coefs[0] = 0;

    helper_glpk.obj_coefs = malloc((nbr_colums + 1) * sizeof(double));
    helper_glpk.obj_coefs[0] = 0;

    helper_glpk.column_of_coef = malloc((nbr_colums + 1) * sizeof(int));
    helper_glpk.column_of_coef[0] = 0;

    helper_glpk.row_of_coef = malloc((nbr_rows + 1) * sizeof(int)); 
    helper_glpk.row_of_coef[0] = 0;

        helper_glpk.col_bounds = malloc((nbr_colums + 1) * sizeof(Bounds *));

for (int index = 0; index <= nbr_colums; index++)
{
    helper_glpk.col_bounds[index] = malloc(sizeof(Bounds));
}

helper_glpk.row_bounds = malloc((nbr_rows + 1) * sizeof(Bounds *));

for (int index = 0; index <= nbr_rows; index++)
{
    helper_glpk.row_bounds[index] = malloc(sizeof(Bounds));
}

    helper_glpk.cpt_coef = 1;

    for(i = 1; i <= baie.nbr_serveur; i++)
        for(j = 1; j <= baie.nbr_client; j++)
            genere_contrainte_1(i, j, &helper_glpk, baie);

    for(i = 1; i <= nbr_colums; i++)
        printf("type[%d] : %d\n", i, helper_glpk.col_bounds[i]->type);

    for(j = 1; j <= baie.nbr_client; j++)
        genere_contrainte_2(j, &helper_glpk, baie.nbr_serveur);
```

The error I get is while I try to printf after the call to generate_contrainte_1

Comment: Please paste the appropriate minimal code here

Comment: Assumin it is `for` or `while` loop, don't you think `i` should start with `0`.

Comment: What's the type/declaration of `helper_glpk.col_bounds`? - ok, just seen it in your pastebin link. But providing pastebin links is not the way to use SO.

Comment: Either `helper_glpk.col_bounds` is too small or the pointer it contains at position 1 is uninitialised or dangling.

Comment: first: post relating code here. second: write code in english so that people not fluent in French can easily understand it.

Comment: BTW: nothing in your code is objective-c. it is plain C.

Comment: Sorry guys I have updated my question

Comment: So I posted relative code here, sorry for that, but I didn't add the objective-c tag, someone else did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
helper_glpk.col_bounds = malloc((nbr_colums + 1) * sizeof(Bounds));
```

You need to fix it with (provided you need nbr_colums + 1 elements):

```
helper_glpk.col_bounds = malloc((nbr_colums + 1) * sizeof(Bounds *));
for (int index = 0; index < nbr_colums + 1; index++)
{
    helper_glpk.col_bounds[index] = malloc(sizeof(Bounds));
}
```

I have not checked the rest of the code, there could be other errors.

Edit: maybe you don't need the for loop depending on what your `genere_contrainte_1` does, but you need to correct your `malloc` with the right `sizeof`.

Edit2: I read your `genere_contrainte_1`, you definitely need all these `malloc`s. But I really doubt you need `row_bounds` and `col_bounds` to be `Bounds **`, it seems to me `Bounds *` would have been fine, and that way a single `malloc` for each field would be enough.

Comment: It was Bounds * at first, but I want to modify col_bounds and row_bounds inside a function, so I think I have to make them pointers ?

Comment: I just updated my code as you said, I now have Bounds *, but it seems that my struct isn't saved, because inside my function I have helper_glpk->col_bounds[1].type = 1; and outside I get the error : type = 216; invalid column type

Comment: You need to call your function this way: `my_function(helper_glpk->col_bounds + i)` and the argument of `my_function` must be a `Bound *`.

Comment: There's no other way to do that ? My function already have helper_glpk as argument, and need other element of helper_glpk so I think you solution is not really good. If I go for Bounds ** should it fix my problem ?

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment is completely wrong. To use `Bounds *` instead of `Bounds **` you need to use `helper_glpk->col_bounds[...].type` inside your `genere_contrainte_1` function.

Comment: Ok, so that's what I did but I still can't have the same value inside and oustide the function, somewhat the value is always overwritten, should I malloc every Bounds ?

Comment: Do you use `printf` to check the values of `index_ouverture_serveur(i)` and `index_connexion(i, j, baie.nbr_serveur)`?

Comment: yeah I do, they are very simple function, for example index_ouverture_serveur(i) return i

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107166/discussion-between-jdarthenay-and-hayanno).